# Volume of tetrahedron

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

For a tetrahedron defined by vectors $OA=\mathbf{a},\;OB=\mathbf{b},\;OC=\mathbf{c}$, the volume is $\frac{1}{6} |\mathbf{a}\cdot (\mathbf{b}\times\mathbf{c})|$

I am wondering, what does the sign of $\mathbf{a}\cdot (\mathbf{b}\times\mathbf{c})$ correspond to? Does it just depend on ordering? For instance, if $\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b},\mathbf{c}$ are stated anticlockwise than the expression is positive and if two are switched it is negative?

Comment: The sign does depend on the ordering: "cycling" the labels $ \ a , b , c \ $ in that order produces a positive result for the scalar triple product, while "cycling" $ \ c, b, a \ $ produces a negative value. (This is because the "cross-product" possesses a "handedness" -- which is useful in certain applications.) For the application you are concerned with, the order is unimportant, so we impose an absolute value on that triple product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's an ordering or "handedness" issue. As you may know, the triple product can be calculated as the value of a determinant whose rows are the components of the three given vectors. Switching the order of the vectors may change the sign of this determinant.

Answer (score 0):

The sign of $\mathbf{a}\cdot (\mathbf{b}\times \mathbf{c})$ depends on the angle formed by the two vectors: $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}\times \mathbf{c}$, if the angle is acute, then then sign is $+$, and it is $-$ if the angle is obtuse.

Comment: The order of $ \ \vec{b} \ $ and $ \ \vec{c} \ $ will also affect the sign of the "cross-product".

Comment: @RecklessReckoner: but can we still define the sign using the "angle" ?

Comment: Since that there are _two_ contributing factors to the sign of the scalar triple product, the sign alone doesn't necessarily tell us about the angle between $ \ \vec{a} \ $ and the plane containing $ \ \vec{b} \ $ and $ \ \vec{c} \ $ .  Swapping the order of the latter two vectors _and_ changing the angle with $ \ \vec{a} \ $ to its supplement leaves the product unchanged.  (Consider, for example, a parallelopiped defined by these vectors, and what the scalar triple product is at one vertex, and at a vertex diagonally opposite across the base.)